# How do you add a hyperlink (i.e. "properties") to a Facebook Feed Dialog in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

My Android app calls the Facebook [Feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) and customizes it like this:

```
Bundle feedDialogParameters = new Bundle();
feedDialogParameters.putString("name", "My Name");
feedDialogParameters.putString("link", "My Link");
feedDialogParameters.putString("picture", "My Picture");
feedDialogParameters.putString("caption", "My Caption");
feedDialogParameters.putString("description", "My Description");

facebook.dialog(getActivity(), "feed", feedDialogParameters, new PostDialogListener());
```

This works great, but now I would like to add some text and a hyperlink to the dialog. I know this is possible through the JavaScript Facebook API, by including a `"properties"` parameter, but I have been unable to find the equivalent for Android. How does one do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this maybe, to see if helps: `parameters.putString("link", "http://www.google.com");`

Comment: That works for linking the picture and the title of the Feed Dialog, which you can see I've done above. But what I'm trying unable to get working is the "properties" parameter, which allows you to include some text with a hyperlink in it.